# finding the limit of $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x^2}$$

It is an expression in form of $\left(\frac{0}{0}\right)$. Using l'Hôpital:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x}{2x}$$

The expression in form of $\left(\frac{1}{0}\right)$ so one-sided limits should be checked

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}} \frac{e^x}{2x}=-\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{e^x}{2x}=\infty$$

Therefore there is no limit

Is this move: The expression in form of $\left(\frac{1}{0}\right)$ so one-sided limits should be checked is right?

Comment: this Limit doesn't exist

Comment: Yes, it's a correct reasoning.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed you are right. Another way to see it:

$$ \begin{align} \lim_{x\to0^{\pm}} \frac{e^x-1}{x^2} &= \lim_{x\to0^{\pm}} \frac{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n/n! } {x^2}\\  &= \lim_{x\to0^{\pm}} \frac1x + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n+2)!}. \end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

You can note that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1
$$
so…

Comment: so I can say it is $lim_{x\to 0} 1 \cdot lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: @gbox More or less; the limit from the right is $\infty$ and the limit from the left is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. When it's $(\frac {1}{0}) $ you should check both sides of the limit, because often it won't exist.

Comment: This looks like to be a comment :-)